# Cannot resolve keyword 'calendar_id' into field. Choices are: description, end_date, event, id, name, owner, owner_id, start_date

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Here is the code where I define the Event and Calendar models:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField( )
    start_time = models.TimeField()  # Example default time
    duration = models.DurationField()  # Example default duration of 1 hour
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the view I am trying to use:

```
class EventListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'EventListView'

    def get_queryset(self):
        calendar_id = self.kwargs['calendar_id']
        return Calendar.objects.filter(calendar_id=calendar_id)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            for event in context['EventListView']:
                event.name = ''
        return context
```

I have another similar view that looks like this, also using the calendar_id and this view works fine. I am not sure why the EventListView is showing this error.

```
class CalendarDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Calendar
    template_name = 'calendars/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'calendar'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'calendar_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Calendar.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `Calendar` as model, not `Event` in the `.get_queryset()`:

```
class EventListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'EventListView'

    def get_queryset(self):
        calendar_id = self.kwargs['calendar_id']
        # 🖟 not Calendar
        return Event.objects.filter(calendar_id=calendar_id)
```

It is probably however better to make a `super()` call, such that you can mix in additional filtering, etc.:

```
class EventListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'EventListView'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(calendar_id=self.kwargs['calendar_id'])
        )
```

---

> **Note**: normally the context object names in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `event_list` instead of <s>`EventListView`</s>.

Comment: Changing from   Calendar.objects.filter(calendar_id=calendar_id) to Event.objects.filter(calendar_id=calendar_id) did the job. Thank you! Was stuck on this for a while.